# Simplest way to save array into raster file in Python

Tags: python, arrays, gis, tiff, raster

With one 2-d array in the shape of (100, 100), I want to save it into raster file in `.tiff` format.

I can use `gdal` package to read `tiff` files which are already exist. But I still can't find a simple way to **transform the 2-d array into tiff file**.

Using `plt.imsave("xx.tif",array)` or

```
def array_to_raster(array):
    """Array > Raster
    Save a raster from a C order array.
    :param array: ndarray
     """
    dst_filename = 'xxx.tiff'
    x_pixels = 100  # number of pixels in x
    y_pixels = 100  # number of pixels in y
    driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')
    dataset = driver.Create(
           dst_filename,
           x_pixels,
           y_pixels,
           1,
           gdal.GDT_Float32, )
    dataset.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(array)
    dataset.FlushCache()  # Write to disk.
    return dataset, dataset.GetRasterBand(1)
```

They all failed to achieve my target. The second method was adapted from [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/58517/python-gdal-save-array-as-raster-with-projection-from-other-file) which can transform an array into a `geotiff` with a projection.

Is there some simple way to save array into `.tiff`, so I can call it by import the `tiff` file next time.

Any advices would be appreciate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A tif raster could be  considered as 'array+proj+geotransforms'.
If you want to write an array to a tiff ,you can refer to the following code:

```
dst_filename = 'xxx.tiff'
x_pixels = 100  # number of pixels in x
y_pixels = 100  # number of pixels in y
driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')
dataset = driver.Create(dst_filename,x_pixels, y_pixels, 1,gdal.GDT_Float32)
dataset.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(array)

# follow code is adding GeoTranform and Projection
geotrans=data0.GetGeoTransform()  #get GeoTranform from existed 'data0'
proj=data0.GetProjection() #you can get from a exsited tif or import 
dataset.SetGeoTransform(geotrans)
dataset.SetProjection(proj)
dataset.FlushCache()
dataset=None
```

Comment: For the record, the last 4 lines should read:

    ```dataset.SetGeoTransform(geotrans)``` 
    ```dataset.SetProjection(proj)```
   ```dataset.FlushCache()```
    ```dataset=None```

Comment: What is `outds` ?

Answer (score 2):

## Easiest way with imageio

If you don't care about its projection it's a oneliner:

```
import imageio
imageio.imwrite('test.tiff', [[0,255],[255,0]])
```