# array to tiff raster image with gdal

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, scipy

Update

i try to follow [this tutorial](https://earthlab.github.io/python/DEM-slope-aspect-python/)

but i dont know how can export to new tiff images slope/aspect with GDAL ?

the full code :

```
from __future__ import division
from osgeo import gdal
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
from matplotlib import colors
import sys
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

filename = 'dem.tif'

def getResolution(rasterfn):
    raster = gdal.Open(rasterfn)
    geotransform = raster.GetGeoTransform()
    res = {"east-west": abs(geotransform[1]), 
           "north-south": abs(geotransform[5])}
    return res

def raster2array(rasterfn):
    raster = gdal.Open(rasterfn)
    band = raster.GetRasterBand(1)
    return band.ReadAsArray()

def getNoDataValue(rasterfn):
    raster = gdal.Open(rasterfn)
    band = raster.GetRasterBand(1)
    return band.GetNoDataValue()

data_array = raster2array(filename)
nodataval = getNoDataValue(filename)
resolution = getResolution(filename)
print(resolution)
print(nodataval)

print(type(data_array))
print(data_array.shape)

num_rows = data_array.shape[0]
num_cols = data_array.shape[1]

slope_array = np.ones_like(data_array) * nodataval
aspect_array = np.ones_like(data_array) * nodataval

for i in range(1, num_rows - 1):
    for j in range(1, num_cols - 1):
        a = data_array[i - 1][j - 1]
        b = data_array[i - 1][j]
        c = data_array[i - 1][j + 1]
        d = data_array[i][j - 1]
        e = data_array[i][j]
        f = data_array[i][j + 1]
        g = data_array[i + 1][j - 1]
        h = data_array[i + 1][j]
        q = data_array[i + 1][j + 1]

        vals = [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, q]

        if nodataval in vals:
            all_present = False
        else:
            all_present = True

        if all_present == True:
            dz_dx = (c + (2 * f) + q - a - (2 * d) - g) / (8 * resolution['east-west'])
            dz_dy = (g + (2 * h) + q - a - (2 * b) - c) / (8 * resolution['north-south'])
            dz_dx_sq = math.pow(dz_dx, 2)
            dz_dy_sq = math.pow(dz_dy, 2)

            rise_run = math.sqrt(dz_dx_sq + dz_dy_sq)
            slope_array[i][j] = math.atan(rise_run) * 57.29578

            aspect = math.atan2(dz_dy, (-1 * dz_dx)) * 57.29578
            if aspect < 0:
                aspect_array[i][j] = 90 - aspect
            elif aspect > 90:
                aspect_array[i][j] = 360 - aspect + 90
            else:
                aspect_array[i][j] = 90 - aspect

hist, bins = np.histogram(slope_array, bins=100, range=(0, np.amax(slope_array)))
width = 0.7 * (bins[1] - bins[0])
center = (bins[:-1] + bins[1:]) / 2
plt.bar(center, hist, align='center', width=width)
plt.xlabel('Slope (degrees)')
plt.ylabel('Frequency')
plt.show()

color_map = ListedColormap(['white', 'darkgreen', 'green', 'limegreen', 'lime', 
                            'greenyellow', 'yellow', 'gold', 
                            'orange', 'orangered', 'red'])

# range begins at negative value so that missing values are white
color_bounds = list(range(-3, math.ceil(np.amax(slope_array)), 1))
color_norm = colors.BoundaryNorm(color_bounds, color_map.N)

#Create the plot and colorbar
img = plt.imshow(slope_array, cmap = color_map, norm = color_norm)
cbar = plt.colorbar(img, cmap = color_map, norm = color_norm,
                   boundaries = color_bounds, ticks = color_bounds)

#Show the visualization
plt.axis('off')
plt.title("Slope (degrees)")
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

first trial to export i follow this [tutorial](https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/raster_layers.html),but the slope in not correct
have lower degrees from the original(using gis program)

```
import gdal, ogr, os, osr
import numpy as np


def array2raster(newRasterfn,rasterOrigin,pixelWidth,pixelHeight,array):

    cols = array.shape[1]
    rows = array.shape[0]
    originX = rasterOrigin[0]
    originY = rasterOrigin[1]

    driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')
    outRaster = driver.Create(newRasterfn, cols, rows, 1, gdal.GDT_Byte)
    outRaster.SetGeoTransform((originX, pixelWidth, 0, originY, 0, pixelHeight))
    outband = outRaster.GetRasterBand(1)
    outband.WriteArray(array)
    outRasterSRS = osr.SpatialReference()
    outRasterSRS.ImportFromEPSG(4326)
    outRaster.SetProjection(outRasterSRS.ExportToWkt())
    outband.FlushCache()


def main(newRasterfn,rasterOrigin,pixelWidth,pixelHeight,array):
    reversed_arr = slope_array # reverse array so the tif looks like the array
    array2raster(newRasterfn,rasterOrigin,pixelWidth,pixelHeight,reversed_arr) # convert array to raster


if __name__ == "__main__":
    rasterOrigin = (-123.25745,45.43013)
    pixelWidth = 10
    pixelHeight = 10
    newRasterfn = 'test.tif'
    array = slope_array

main(newRasterfn,rasterOrigin,pixelWidth,pixelHeight,array)
```

second trial i follow this [quest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37648439/simplest-way-to-save-array-into-raster-file-in-python) but i dont take some export

```
def array_to_raster(slope_array):
    """Array > Raster
    Save a raster from a C order array.
    :param array: ndarray
     """
    dst_filename = 'xxx.tiff'
    x_pixels = num_rows # number of pixels in x
    y_pixels = num_cols # number of pixels in y
    driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')
    dataset = driver.Create(
           dst_filename,
           x_pixels,
           y_pixels,
           1,
           gdal.GDT_Float32, )
    dataset.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(array)
    dataset.FlushCache()  # Write to disk.
    return dataset, dataset.GetRasterBand(1)
```

any idea

Answer (score 1):

The error states exactly what the problem is. You are trying to multiply an `int` type by a `NoneType` (None). The most likely case is that `nodataval` is None, which would occur because the NoDataValue for filename's first raster band is not defined. Your print(nodataval) command should demonstrate that. <strike>Remember, printing None doesn't appear as the string 'None'. It appears as a blank or no character.</strike>

Your edits show that nodataval is None.

Comment: how can i fix that ?maybe i replace none with the some numbers like 0 ?i a good idea ?

Comment: If your raster/dem doesn't have areas to mask out, then this is irrelevant. Look through the code and see where nodata checks are made and modify the code appropriately. You shouldn't just abitrarily set a nodata value, because 0 might be an important value. Such a case would be if you are near sea level. If you need a quick fix, set nodataval=-9999999 or something impossible for your dataset.

Comment: yeah I understood this i import check with some if and i need two way to complete this script one way with dem with nodata value and another way without nodata,correct?one more question how to export slope/aspect to new image file like tiff?no plot image i want new image with new values...thnx to to help me

Comment: You don't need to modify the script very much. After `nodataval = getNoDataValue(filename)` write two more lines `if nodataval is None:    nodataval = -99999`. You don't have to modify the rest of the script.  If you want to output a georeferenced tiff you should look at GDAL. It has python bindings that help convert numpy arrays into tiffs. GDAL also has command line prorams that will compute slope and aspect. It is very powerful.

Comment: i have gdal  in my system but i am very new in the club,i dont know much and i need that export