# How to convert array to tiff file?

Tags: python, raster, geotiff

i am getting responses in NumPy array of a ndvi tiff file. I want to download this tiff file, what is the procedure or  python code need help?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37648439/simplest-way-to-save-array-into-raster-file-in-python) can help? Please try to search for information before asking.

Comment: yes am facing same problem but i tried this solution but it not work for me.

Comment: You should give some more infos and your code.